# Strawpoll.me API returns "400 Bad Request" for my Python program, but works from terminal

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest, aiohttp

I have the following Python program to create strawpolls using strawpoll.me's API as described [here.](https://github.com/strawpoll/strawpoll/wiki/API)

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def createPoll():
    question = "Is this thing on?"
    options = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"]

    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post(
                "https://www.strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls",
                json={
                    "title": question,
                    "options": options,
                    "multi": "false"
                },
                headers={"Content Type": "application/json"}
            ) as response:
                print(response)
                json = await response.json()
                strawpoll_id = json["id"]
            print(f"https://strawpoll.me/{strawpoll_id}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(createPoll())
```

This used to work, but it isn't any more. I'm wondering what changed. Here's what I get now:

```
<ClientResponse(https://www.strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls) [400 Bad Request]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '0')>

0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: '
>>>
```

If I send the same parameters to the endpoint in a terminal like this:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title": "Is this this on?", "options": ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"], "multi": "false"}' https://www.strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls`

I get the expected response.

Comment: `Content Type` -> `Content-Type` ?

Comment: I don't think it's part of the error but your `title` is different. `Is this this on?` (code) and `Is this thing on?` (curl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried:

```py
async def createPoll():
    question = "Is this thing on?"
    options = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"]

    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            print('HERE')
            async with session.post(
                "https://www.strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls",
                json={
                    "title": question,
                    "options": options,
                    "multi": "false"
                },
                headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
            ) as response:
                print(response)
                json = await response.json()
                strawpoll_id = json["id"]
            print(f"https://strawpoll.me/{strawpoll_id}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The only thing I changed was `Content Type` to `Content-Type` and the output I got:

```
<ClientResponse(https://www.strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Cache-Control': 'private, no-cache="set-cookie"', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'Set-Cookie': 'AWSELB=193D972F16169235196B775BF1B5BFF2D266A3E7F134840A661FD488EC125877D4193B20C4FCDBDB753E1C0E576E03398F3B7AAE5AAC9D70BFE31DB4F45EABEEB6F46BFBEE;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=3600', 'Set-Cookie': 'AWSELBCORS=193D972F16169235196B775BF1B5BFF2D266A3E7F134840A661FD488EC125877D4193B20C4FCDBDB753E1C0E576E03398F3B7AAE5AAC9D70BFE31DB4F45EABEEB6F46BFBEE;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=3600;SECURE;SAMESITE=None', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=edge,chrome=1', 'Content-Length': '140', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Date': 'Fri, 06 Mar 2020 07:47:42 GMT', 'Via': '1.1 varnish', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-hhn4027-HHN', 'X-Cache': 'MISS', 'X-Cache-Hits': '0', 'X-Timer': 'S1583480862.671417,VS0,VE458', 'Set-Cookie': 'Geo={%22region%22:%22HE%22%2C%22country%22:%22DE%22%2C%22continent%22:%22EU%22}; path=/; domain=.strawpoll.me; SameSite=None; Secure;', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=300')>
```

Comment: Okay, I feel a little silly now :') It was just a single missing hyphen. I went back to my earlier commits to confirm the code that actually used to work, and it definitely worked when it used to be `Content Type`, so I've no idea why it changed. Maybe the API expects it written this way? Solved either way.